# move the tr of the table to be visible in the table by using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

The example is as follows:

see : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6jwk3c8b/)

or:

```
<body>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>......</option>
        <option>21</option>
    </select>

    <div style="overflow:auto;height:50%;width:50%">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>

                <th>Rowno</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>$100</td>
                <th>t1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>$300</td>
                <th>t2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>$400</td>
                <th>t3</th>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>$200</td>
                <th>t5</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

As the example in the jsfiddle above,assuming that the row 21st. is invisible in the table unless you scroll the scrollbar to the bottom,so if I want to  move the the row 21st. of the table to be visible in the table when selecting a rowno in the select options by using js or jquery,could you please tell me how to write this js? thanks.

Comment: There's a reason the system wouldn't let you post a link only to fiddle. Post your code in question itself. We shouldn't have to go off site just to find out what basic issue is. Now..just to help you we have to copy and paste a link. Not a good way to ask for help

Comment: Need a far better problem description. There is nothing in demo but an unstyled , unconstrained table

Comment: are you saying that you want to ensure row 21 is visible on initial load? or you want a button to scroll down to next page, or a button to scroll down to 21.  If you just want a link to get u to row 21 then you could look at simple <a> name tags.

Comment: <select> 
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>......</option> 
 <option>21</option>
  </select> 
when select a rowno in the select option ,moving the invisible row correspoding with selected rowno to be visible in the table or window.

Comment: so now you are simply asking how to filter? nothing to do with scrolling? Please provide a proper description of behaviors expected

Comment: so is [this (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/dtfuyzcd/2/) what you are looking for?  Code not working, but select a row # from drop down and ensure it is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery. You can use the hide function.  Your  would require a class.

```
$('.trhideclass1').hide();

<tr class="trhideclass1">
    <td>......</td>
</tr>
```